# Schedule multiple tasks, where the execution of those tasks can be paused in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a very simple console program which reads in dates from a file and then schedules tasks based on those dates. Sometimes there are errors which the program cannot handle by itself so the user has to intervene. I want to pause execution on all tasks until the user manually resumes the execution.

The process would go as follows:

1. Read File
2. Schedule n tasks
3. Execute each task on designated date
4. Error occurs in one task
5. Execution stops for all tasks
6. Users presses enter (or inputs some characters, or whatever)
7. Execution resumes and the programm catches up with all tasks that it might have missed while waiting for user input

I was looking at Timer and ExecutorService, but i think there should be Coroutine-centric solution.

Im not really sure how to tackle this problem and would be grateful if someone could guide me into the right direction.

Comment: You can absolutely do this using coroutines! My best advice is: Just get started, and if you get stuck, ask a specific question with details.

Comment: Also note that you won't be able to pause whenever you want, whether you're using raw threads or coroutines. Suspension of coroutines is cooperative. Coroutines can only suspend in specific places in their code (suspension points). But yeah you can in theory control this, probably with a custom dispatcher

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.